# react-loadable callback when load done?

Tags: reactjs, react-loadable

Is there any callback for react-loadable when it loaded the component? I can not find any info in the [document](https://github.com/jamiebuilds/react-loadable) of react-loadable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may make use of its `loader` property or `render` method:

```
Loadable({
  loader: () =>
    import("./components/Bar").then(Bar => {
      console.log("loaded"); // Put your callback here
      return Bar;
    }),
});
```

or,

```
Loadable({
  loader: () => import("./components/Bar"),
  render(loaded, props) {
    console.log("loaded"); // Put your callback here
    let Component = loaded.default;
    return <Component {...props} />;
  },
});
```